# Converting an char to int without getting the Ascii dec value

Tags: c++, vector, char, integer, ascii

I try to read data from a text file. The .get function of the istream reads a 5 in the txt-File but returns the corresponding ascii dec value which is 53. I want to convert that value to 5.

One line of the text file is formatted like that:

Format: [Text] = [Value]

Ex.:    Config Value = 5

.

The code that is reading from the text file is:

```
tmpTxt.ignore(100, '='); //skips past the =
tmpTxt.ignore(100, ' '); //skips past the space
ConfigVec.push_back(tmpTxt.get()); //reads value and pushes it back to the vector(I want this value to be 5)
```

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing it? Finding an ascii-table should be easy, figuring out  how to convert an ascii-code to the numeric value should be easy to. Please add some more details to describe the problems you've encoutered.

Comment: I already tried the common methods of converting chars to int like casting and that stuff. I think that it is odd to copy the whole ascii table and hardcode it into the code...

Comment: So you want something like `atoi` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) except that it natively works with single chars?

Comment: Yeahh, exactly that. Thanks